# What layer should a filter servlet fall into

Tags: architecture, package

Am working on a spring-jsf project, am trying to follow a layered approach, which layer should a servlet filter fall into ? business or cross-cutting or is it another layer?

Answer (score 0):

A servlet should be the UI layer.  It is a UI concern.  People often use them as controllers, because it is very convenient to do so, but from a reuse standpoint they should take the input and pass it to the controller layer.

Many people don't like to write a separate controller, as it ends up looking VERY simple when you have a UI layer like a servlet in front of it...